# woo commerce new account registration

Tags: wordpress

I have add the field on registration form for phone number

```html
<p class="form-row form-row-wide"> <label for="reg_billing_phone">Phone <span class="required">*</span></label> <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value=""></p>
```

Onece user register my website admin geting bellow email but they are missing phone number

Thanks for creating an account on our website . Your username is sales

Your password has been automatically generated: %6h51J$xFK)Z

Phone No:(i want print here phone number)

You can access your account area to view your orders and change your

Email Template:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<p><?php printf( __( 'Thanks for creating an account on %1$s. Your username is %2$s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $blogname ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_login ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>

<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) && $password_generated ) : ?>

<p><?php printf( __( 'Your password has been automatically generated: %s', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_pass ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>
<p>Phone No:<?php echo get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', true ) ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<p><?php printf( __( 'You can access your account area to view your orders and change your password here: %s.', 'woocommerce' ), make_clickable( esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) ); ?></p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Comment: Take a look at WooCommerce's [custom fields](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

Comment: i saw my field also perfectly working but when user register in i am getting email only customer user name and password  i want to print phone number too

Comment: The phone number is present in the user's account? If that's the case, you have to show the code for the email.

Comment: yes this phone no appear Customer billing address Phone field but not printing registration email

Comment: Please include the code for the email, otherwise no one can help.

Comment: my field code is: <p class="form-row form-row-wide"> <label for="reg_billing_phone">Phone <span class="required">*</span></label> <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value=""></p>

Comment: Edit the question to include it. Also, the code for the email, not the registration field.

Comment: Hi mcon please go through for email code : https://jsfiddle.net/2m5kmh1s/1/

Comment: Please check my email code :https://jsfiddle.net/2m5kmh1s/1/ @mcon

Comment: I added the template code to the question in case the jsfiddle link dies

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `$customer_id` is set in the email template. If it's not set, you'll have to get the user in PHP so you can query user meta. This should work if `$customer_id` isn't available in the script.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

$user = get_user_by('login', $user_login);

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<p><?php printf( __( 'Thanks for creating an account on %1$s. Your username is %2$s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $blogname ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_login ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>

<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) && $password_generated ) : ?>

<p><?php printf( __( 'Your password has been automatically generated: %s', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_pass ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>
<p>Phone No:<?php echo get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'billing_phone', true ) ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<p><?php printf( __( 'You can access your account area to view your orders and change your password here: %s.', 'woocommerce' ), make_clickable( esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) ); ?></p>
```